# Get list of IP from line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I get inputs of the form `<an arbitrary number of words> <a list of ip addresses comma separated> <timestamp>`.

I tried to get `ip_list=$(echo $i | sed 's/\([0-9\.,]\)+/\1/')`, where `$i` is a line on the previously described form, but that matches the whole line for some reason.

The list of IPs does not have spaces in the middle, just commas.

I would like to get the ip list (as a block) and the timestamp in two bash variables.

**Example input**

```
asdf asaskf a aghjjsdf 127.0.0.1,10.0.1.1,8.8.8.8,124.125.163.124 2013-11-22 08:38:12
```

**Output**

```
ip_variable="127.0.0.1,10.0.1.1,8.8.8.8,124.125.163.124"
date_variable="2013-11-22 08:38:12"
```

Comment: Please provide example input and wanted output.

Comment: This example in not god.  Are IP address always placed at same location?  Does the number of IP vary? etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (under default IFS)

```
read -a arr <<<'asdf asaskf a aghjjsdf 127.0.0.1,10.0.1.1,8.8.8.8,124.125.163.124 2013-11-22 08:38:12'
ip_variable="${arr[-3]}"
echo $ip_variable
127.0.0.1,10.0.1.1,8.8.8.8,124.125.163.124
date_variable="${arr[*]:(-2)}"
echo $date_variable
2013-11-22 08:38:12
```

Comment: Good to know bash can use -3 index.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${i}" | sed 's/^.*[[:blank:]]\(\(\([012][0-9]\{1,2\}.\)\{3\}[012][0-9]\{1,2\}[.[:blank:]]\)\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$/\1 \4/' | read ip_variable date_variable
```

failed if ip are not separate only by `,`

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with `grep -P (PCRE)`:

```
> s='asdf asaskf a aghjjsdf 127.0.0.1,10.0.1.1,8.8.8.8,124.125.163.124 2013-11-22 08:38:12'
> arr=( $(echo "$s"| grep -oP '(\d+\.){3}\d') )
> set | grep arr
arr=([0]="127.0.0.1" [1]="10.0.1.1" [2]="8.8.8.8" [3]="124.125.163.1")

> ts=$(echo "$s"| grep -oP '\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} .*')
> echo "$ts"
2013-11-22 08:38:12
```